# One or more participants failed to draw() + Cannot read property 'Do' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is a Google chart that I worked with by importing data with ajax. The chart that was working fine suddenly pops up and doesn't work.
What should I do to solve it? Below is the source I worked on.

One or more participants failed to draw() Cannot read property 'Do' of undefined
Errors occur at the same time

What can be done to solve it?

***code***

```
  var chartDrowFun = {

        chartDrow : function(){
        var app_tot = new Array();
        var app_mode = $('#app_mode').val();
//      console.log(month);
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "app/test.php",
            async   : false,
            data    : {'year' : year, 'month' : month, 'app_mode' : app_mode},
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(response) {              
//              console.log(response);
                app_tot = response;     
                var and_c = app_tot["and_c"];
                var ios_c = app_tot["ios_c"];
//                  console.log(jhs[0]['and_c']);
            }
        });
//      console.log(app_tot);
        var chartData = '';
        //날짜형식 변경하고 싶으시면 이 부분 수정하세요.
        var chartDateformat     = 'yyyy년MM월dd일';
        //라인차트의 라인 수
        var chartLineCount    = app_tot.length;
        //컨트롤러 바 차트의 라인 수
        var controlLineCount    = 0;
        function drawDashboard() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          //그래프에 표시할 컬럼 추가
          data.addColumn('datetime' , '날짜');
          data.addColumn('number'   , 'IOS');
          data.addColumn('number'   , 'ANDROID');
          data.addColumn('number'   , '전체');            
         
          //그래프에 표시할 데이터
          var dataRow = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < app_tot.length; i++){ //랜덤 데이터 생성      
//            console.log(jhs[i]['ios_c']);
            var ios   = getNum(parseFloat(app_tot[i]['ios_c']));
            var and   = getNum(parseFloat(app_tot[i]['and_c']));
            var total   = getNum(ios + and);
            console.log(and);
            dataRow = [new Date(year, month-1, i+1, 0 ), ios, and , total];
            data.addRow(dataRow);
          }
          
            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
              chartType   : 'LineChart',
              containerId : 'lineChartArea', //라인 차트 생성할 영역
              options     : {
                              isStacked   : 'percent',
                              focusTarget : 'category',
                              height          : 500,
                              width           : '100%',
                              legend          : { position: "top", textStyle: {fontSize: 13}},
                              pointSize     : 5,
                              tooltip         : {textStyle : {fontSize:12}, showColorCode : true,trigger: 'both'},
                              hAxis           : {format: chartDateformat, gridlines:{count:chartLineCount,units: {
                                                                  years : {format: ['yyyy년']},
                                                                  months: {format: ['MM월']},
                                                                  days  : {format: ['dd일']},
                                                                  hours : {format: ['HH시']}}
                                                                },textStyle: {fontSize:12}},
                vAxis             : {minValue: 10,viewWindow:{min:0},gridlines:{count:-1},textStyle:{fontSize:12}},
                animation       : {startup: true,duration: 1000,easing: 'in' },
                annotations : {pattern: chartDateformat,
                                textStyle: {
                                fontSize: 15,
                                bold: true,
                                italic: true,
                                color: '#871b47',
                                auraColor: '#d799ae',
                                opacity: 0.8,
                                pattern: chartDateformat
                              }
                            }
              }
            });
            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
              controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
              containerId: 'controlsArea',  //control bar를 생성할 영역
              options: {
                  ui:{
                        chartType: 'LineChart',
                        chartOptions: {
                        chartArea: {'width': '60%','height' : 80},
                          hAxis: {'baselineColor': 'none', format: chartDateformat, textStyle: {fontSize:12},
                            gridlines:{count:controlLineCount,units: {
                                  years : {format: ['yyyy년']},
                                  months: {format: ['MM월']},
                                  days  : {format: ['dd일']},
                                  hours : {format: ['HH시']}}
                            }}
                        }
                  },
                    filterColumnIndex: 0
                }
            });
            var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: chartDateformat});
            date_formatter.format(data, 0);
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('Line_Controls_Chart'));
            window.addEventListener('resize', function() { dashboard.draw(data); }, false); //화면 크기에 따라 그래프 크기 변경
            dashboard.bind([control], [chart]);
            dashboard.draw(data);
        }
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line','controls']});
      chartDrowFun.chartDrow(); //chartDrow() 실행
    });
```

Comment: wait a minute, this isn't php. it's javascript.

Comment: See this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-visualization%5D+%22one+or+more+participants+failed+to+draw%22) for related questions

Comment: I've seen this error, it is a bug, but can't remember exactly where. first, try changing the version loaded, instead of --> `'current'` -- try -- `'50'`, or `'49'`, etc. -- see the [releases](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) page for more...

Comment: Setting the loaded version from 'current' to '50' solved this for me.

Comment: I recommend always using a _frozen_ version, to prevent changes to the _current_ version from causing issues...